# Adding interactivity to Pdf file (add custom highlight and bookmarks)

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, pdf-generation, customization

I want to add interactivity to Pdf file. Just like to read text from pdf, add highlight to a certain part of text and bookmark some pages.
I've tried many dependencies but not able to achieve proper output.
Attaching images for the reference output.

[image]

I want to achieve similar output but it should be customized. Because many packages aren't providing customization functionality.
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: @Imtiaz yeah, I used syncfusion_flutter_pdf. A few months this library wasn't providing the annotation functionality so I utilized it's read, write (replace with my new text), and update the pdf.
But now, it's very easy. syncfusion_flutter_pdf is providing annotation functionality. You can try it.